# changing the date format in shell script

Tags: shell, date, python-2.7, sed, awk

I have a string and I need to separate the country name and date.

```
# echo 'india16-Feb-2013-20-33.sql' |  sed 's/[0-9][0-9]//' | awk -F"-" '{print $1}'
india

# echo 'india16-Feb-2013-20-33.sql' |  sed 's/india//' | awk -F"." '{print $1}'
16-Feb-2013-20-33
```

1) Is the above sed + awk correct? Is there any better way?

2) How do I format the date as **2013-02-16 20:33:00**

I got the string (16-Feb) mentioned above using the following command. But I do not know how to change it back.

```
date '+%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M'
```

Comment: are  you using a modern linux system, or an old-line Unixen (Sun, HP, AIX, etc)? Note the the tag date has only 89 followers, so consider swapping that tag for a OS tag. In a new GNU based-linux this can be done in 1 awk cmd (calling gnudate for the conversion). Good luck.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am starting to love `sed`

```sh
$ cat a.txt
india16-Feb-2013-20-33.sql

$ sed 's/[0-9].*//' a.txt
india

$ sed 's/[a-z]*//; s/-/ /3; s/-/:/3; s/.sql//' a.txt | xargs -0 date '+%F %T' -d
2013-02-16 20:33:00
```

Comment: There are a few cases where the country name ends with a number. for e.g. india2 In such cases the date should be selected as 2 digits + "-"

Answer (score 3):

I couldn't get the `sed` with `date` versions working on `osx` so I did a Python version.

```
import datetime
import re
datestr = 'india16-Feb-2013-20-33.sql'

(country, date) = re.findall('(.*?)(\d{2}-.{3}-\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}).*', datestr)[0]

dt = datetime.datetime.strptime(date, "%d-%b-%Y-%H-%M")

print "country=", country
print "dt=", dt
```

Gives:

```
country= india
dt= 2013-02-16 20:33:00
```

Comment: http://tinyurl.com/c6crrdq # Can you please check if the if else logic used is correct or if there is a better way to do the same?

Answer (score 0):

Using `sed` and a single substitution:

```
sed 's/.*\([0-9]\{2\}-[A-Z][a-z]\{2\}-[0-9]\{4\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\)-\([0-9]\{2\}\).*/date -d "\1 \2\3" +"%F %T"/ge'
```

Personally, I find it's a little bit easier on the eyes using `GNU sed`:

```
sed -r 's/.*([0-9]{2}-[A-Z][a-z]{2}-[0-9]{4})-([0-9]{2})-([0-9]{2}).*/date -d "\1 \2\3" +"%F %T"/ge'
```

Results:

```
2013-02-16 20:33:00
```